# Meaning of "event $A$ is a subset of event $B$"

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory

A very simple question:
Given two events $A$ and $B$.
In my notes it is given, if set $A$ occurs, so does $B$ → $A$ is a subset of $B$.

I really don't get the logic. Shouldn't it be the other way round. 
Suppose $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, how does happening of $A$ guarantee happening of $B$?

I think a mistake has been made in the notes. Kindly clarify.

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear.

"... if set A occurs, so does B → A is a subset of B."
Is this saying that B implies that A is a subset of B? I have never heard of a set "occurring"" and no relation has been defined between A and B (ex. B contains some elements of A / All elements of B are in A / etc). They can both be different sets.

In your example, A is a subset of B because every element in A is an element of B. Every element of B is not an element of A so B is not a subset of A.

Comment: @August Just guessing, but maybe user46697 is taking a class in probability or statistics, and the sets $A,B$ are events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an element of $A$ is selected, then an element of $B$ be is selected. This is true for all elements of $A$. In other words, $B$ happening means 
$1$, $2$, $3$,$4$, or $5$ has happened. If $a\in A$ happens, then $1,2$ or $3$ happens and thus it is certainly true that $1,2,3,4$ or $5$ has happened. Thus $B$ has also happened.

The converse ('the other way around' ) is not true.
If I select $5$ or $4$, then $B$ has occurred but not $A$; hence
$$A\subsetneq B.$$

Your notes are fine.

I think another equivalent definition is 
$A$ is a subset of $B$ if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$ for all $x\in A$.